# How to determine the type of an enum inherited from ushort?

Tags: c#, enums

If I declare an enum inheriting from ushort like this:

```
public enum MyEnum : ushort { A = 0, B = 1 };
```

and then check its type like this:

```
if(typeof(MyEnum) != typeof(ushort))
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

The breakpoint is called. Why is this happening?

Comment: For the same reason that `typeof(string) != typeof(object)`.

Comment: That's not an inheritance declaration - it declares the underlying type of the enum.

Comment: @cdhowie: Not really... `MyEnum` doesn't really inherit from `ushort`.

Comment: @JonSkeet No, but the concepts are similar and comparing his conditional with the one I wrote helps to illustrate the reason that his conditional doesn't work as he expected -- even if the reasons are not exactly the same, they are close enough to communicate the point.

Comment: @cdhowie: I'd argue that the OP has potentially two different misconceptions - you've effectively highlighted one which *wasn't* really going on here, missing the other one.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, you already addressed the other one... no need for me to pile on.

Comment: @cdhowie: Okay - just for completeness, I'll mention your point (and the equivalent fix) in the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called because they're not the same type! One is an enum type with an underlying value of type `ushort`, and the other is `ushort` itself. (Note that it's not really "inheriting from `ushort`" even though it uses the same syntax - it's really just saying "the underlying type is `ushort`".)

Why would you *expect* them to be the same type? If they were actually the same type, you'd lose a lot of the type safety of enums.

It would be very odd to print `typeof(MyEnum).Name` and get `UInt16` IMO.

If you're trying to determine the underlying type, you should use [`Type.GetEnumUnderlyingType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getenumunderlyingtype.aspx):

```
if (typeof(MyEnum).GetEnumUnderlyingType() == typeof(ushort))
{
    // Yup, the underlying type is ushort
}
```

EDIT: Just for completeness, if `MyEnum` really *did* inherit from `ushort`, you'd still be testing for type *equality*. As cdhowie says in the comments, if you wrote:

```
if (typeof(string) != typeof(object))
{
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

that would *still* break into the debugger. You might want to look at [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) for situations where you really want to make that kind of comparison.

Comment: Ok so how can I represent an enum of underlying value type of ushort in that statement?  I.E how can I ensure the enum is of value type ushort?

Comment: @Lukesmith: See my edit - if that doesn't do what you want it to, please clarify.